# Passing GeoLocation in HTML5 to PHP

Tags: php, html

I am working on a personal project and have run into an error. I am kind of combining multiple tutorials in order to create a way for Geolocation to be determined, and then submit to a database. 
I am running into an issue where once I press the "go" button, I have to press it again in order for the data to be passed off. I may be going about this an extremely complicated way, but maybe you can help. Thanks.

```
<script>
    var latitude    = 0;
    var longitude   = 0;

    function geoFindMe() {
      var output = document.getElementById("show");

      if (!navigator.geolocation){
        output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
        return;
      }

      function success(position) {
        latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '<br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '</p>';
      };

      function error() {
        output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
      };

      output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating...</p>";
      fillLatitudeLongitudeElements();
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

    function fillLatitudeLongitudeElements(){
        document.getElementById("latitude").value = latitude;
        document.getElementById("longitude").value = longitude;

        var sql = "INSERT INTO gps(lat, long) VALUES (latitude,longitude)";
    }
}

</script>

<p><button onclick="geoFindMe()">Locate</button></p>
<div id="show"></div>

 <?php include "../dbconnect.php";

 if(isset($_POST['sub'])){

     $l = $_POST['long'];

     $la = $_POST['lat'];

     $n = $_POST['name'];

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `gps`(`lat`, `long`, `name`) VALUES ('".$la."','".$l."','".$n."')");

 echo "Done though";

 }
 ?>

<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    Latitude3:<br>
    <input id="latitude" type="text" name="firstname" value="latitude" readonly><br>
    Longitude:<br>
    <input id="longitude" type="text" name="lastname" value="longitude" readonly><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: What is supposed to be happening? What seems to be going wrong?

Comment: Here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Sy6P0J1VjQ